# How to create ''table" in HTML using values from one field with XML data?

Tags: php, html, xml

I am not PHP professional so I need help with this.
I am working with some PHP application.
I have one STRING field1 with XML data format in it:

```
$field1='<messages>
  <person id="501">
    <name>Jan</name>
    <surname>Scott</surname>
  </note>
  <person id="502">
    <name>Mark</name>
    <surname>Cruise</surname>
  </person>
</messages>';
```

I need to put in field2 (which is HTML type) table which will contain this look:

```
NAME   SURNAME

JAN    SCOTT
MARK   CRUISE
```

What will be php script to parse from that first field to second field that values?

Thank you!!

Comment: There is a big difference between *needing help* and *needing someone to do it for you*. Have you tried anything to do it?

Comment: ok sorry but I do not know if this is too complicated? maybe some guidance? As I said I am not PHP developer so I will apprecite help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to easily traverse your XML string. Then you can simply construct the html output with something like

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($field1);

$html = "<table>";
$html .= "<tr><td>NAME</td><td>SURNAME</td></tr>";

foreach($person in $xml->person) {
  $html .= "<tr><td>" . $person->name . "</td><td>" . $person->surname . "</td></tr>";
}

$html .= "</table>";
```

Didn't try the code but the basic idea is like that. If you want uppercase you add that.

Second... PHP normally does not add the keyword *var* to variables anymore and every variablename should be prepended with *$*. Also strings should be contained within quotes.
So just

```
$field1 = '<messages><person id="501"><name>Jan</name><surname>Scott</surname></note><person id="502"><name>Mark</name><surname>Cruise</surname></person></messages>';
```

If you want to have multi-line strings you should look at the [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

If you MUST prepend your variables with *var* you might be using a quite old version of PHP and then several of my comments might not apply. If that is the case, update you PHP installation or come back here with what version of PHP you are running.

Comment: thank you, no you were right I should use $. Tell me how to be sure that I can use this SimpleXMLElement? Do I have to do some import, or include, extends class or something? I am not sure that my application (Sugar CRM) supports automatically this Class.

Comment: No, SimpleXML is part of the standard libs/classes of PHP. Try a simple script `<?php $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(); ?>`. If it complains about SimpleXMLElement then you might not have it. But my guess is that you do.

Comment: OK I will try and let you know. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
$xmlString = '<messages>
  <person id="501">
    <name>Jan</name>
    <surname>Scott</surname>
  </person>
  <person id="502">
    <name>Mark</name>
    <surname>Cruise</surname>
  </person>
</messages>';


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
echo "<table border='1' width='50%'>";
echo "<tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>SurName</td>
    </tr>";
foreach ($xml as $element)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $element["id"];
    echo "</td>";
    foreach ($element as $key => $val)
    {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $val;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

This code will convert your xml to basic html table.

Comment: thank you for response but if I test it on my local php file I am getting some strange output. Do I have to somehow import or include or extend this SimpleXMLElement class to be able to use it? thank you